# Set the width of a th element depending on other td width

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, fixed-header-tables

I have an html table designed using twitter bootstrap and I fixed the table's header row to fixed using [Fixed TableRC](http://meetselva.github.io/fixed-table-rows-cols/) plugin as given in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4HgV2/1/). The header's th width is set as

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var modal = [];
   var ColNums = document.getElementById('fixed_hdr2').rows[0].cells.length;

   for (var i = 1; i < ColNums+1; i++) {
       var row = $("#fixed_hdr2 th:nth-child("+i+")").width();
    // var row = 30;
       modal.push({ width: row, align: 'center' });
    } 

    $('#fixed_hdr2').fxdHdrCol({
        fixedCols:  0,
        width:     "100%",
        height:    "364px",
        colModal:  modal,
    //  sort: true
    });
   });
```

And it work fine for blank table. When I added some values inside the `td` of the table, the alignment of the column slightly altered as given in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4HgV2/3/) and [in this case also](http://jsfiddle.net/4HgV2/25/). How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries, the issue is solved by setting the width of all `td`'s to the width of respective `th` of header row by using jquery `.width()` property as,

```
var ColNums = document.getElementById('fixed_hdr2').rows[0].cells.length;

   for (var i = 1; i < ColNums+1; i++) {
       var row = $(".ft_r th:nth-child("+i+")").width();
       $("#fixed_hdr2 td:nth-child("+i+")").width(row);
    }
```

and setting `word-break:break-all` as

```
#fixed_hdr2 tr td {
 word-break:break-all;      
        }
```

as @Bhushan Kawadkar suggested.

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4HgV2/27/)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you are adding text and column width taking space equal to width of word with maximum length i.e. without breaking a word.
 If you add `word-break:break-all` to you `modal` array then this will resolve your issue :

```
modal.push({ width: row, align: 'center' ,word-break:'break-all'});
```

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4HgV2/7/)